# How can I make a virtual column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Here is my query:

```
    $first = DB::table('news')
        ->select(['id', 'title', 'description', 'imgPath'])
        ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', "$q%")
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', "$q%");
        });

    $result = DB::table('productions')
        ->select(['id', 'title', 'description', 'imgPath'])
        ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', "$q%")
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', "$q%");
        })
        ->unionAll($first)
        ->get();
```

As you see I've used `union all` which merges the results of those two different queries. Ok well, now I need to know, each row *(of the result table)* belongs to which table. Because of that I need to add one more column to the `select` part and set it a default value. Then use that value to detect row's table.

In pure SQL it can be something like this:

```
SELECT 'news' as tableName, col1, col2 FROM news WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'productions' as tableName, col1, col2 FROM productions WHERE ...
```

Then in PHP:

```
if ( $result['tableName'] == 'news' ) {
    // this row belongs to "news" table
} elseif( $result['tableName'] == 'productions' ) { 
    // this row belongs to "productions" table
}
```

How can I do that in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the selectRaw() method instead of select():

```
$first = DB::table('news')
    ->selectRaw('"news" as tableName, id, title, description, imgPath')
    ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
        $query->where('title', 'like', "$q%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', "$q%");
    });

$result = DB::table('productions')
    ->selectRaw('"productions" as tableName, id, title, description, imgPath')
    ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
        $query->where('title', 'like', "$q%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', "$q%");
    })
    ->unionAll($first)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Raw Expression` `->select(DB::raw('news' as tableName, col1, col2'))`

FYI, https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can use DB::raw for this

```
 DB::raw('news as tableName')

 DB::raw('productions as tableName')
```

in the select part